# RSL10 issue with SPI

Tags: embedded, spi

I am working on a project where I need to connect a sensor to an rsl10 with SPI. I was able to set up the right pins with the CMSIS driver and a think that the initialization works. To test the connection I hooked up the CS-Signal to an oscilloscope: Before the initialization the signal is floating, then when initialized the signal is high (SPI inactive). After the initialization I set the SPI connection to "active" in the code and the signal corespondingly goes low.

But there is where the issues start: then I try to receive data with `spi0->Receive(sensor_data, 12);`. This should read data from SPI0, then go into the defined callback function and set the CS back to high. But it seems like it never enters the callback function and hence is also unable to set the CS back to high. I have talked to experts form my university but we were not able to figure out why it wont work properly. Now I really hope that someone who is an expert with the rsl10 can help me to get the SPI interface working.

To really see how I implemented it so far I attached snippets the my main application file.

I hope i have worded my issue understandably, will gladly answer questions to clarify things and really hope that someone out there can help me.

Initialisation:

```c
/* Initialize spi0 driver structure */
spi0 = &Driver_SPI0;
/* Initialize spi0, register callback function */
spi0->Initialize(SPI0_Master_CallBack);
/* Power up the SPI peripheral */
spi0->PowerControl(ARM_POWER_FULL);
/* Configure the SPI to Master, 8-bit mode @10000 kBits/sec */
spi0->Control(ARM_SPI_MODE_MASTER | ARM_SPI_CPOL1_CPHA1 | ARM_SPI_MSB_LSB | ARM_SPI_SS_MASTER_SW | ARM_SPI_DATA_BITS(8), 10000000);
/* SS line = INACTIVE = HIGH */
spi0->Control(ARM_SPI_CONTROL_SS, ARM_SPI_SS_INACTIVE);
// Set default TX Value for reading
spi0->Control(ARM_SPI_SET_DEFAULT_TX_VALUE, 0x80);
```

Callback:

```c
/* Check event */
switch (event) {
    /* Transfer complete event */
    case ARM_SPI_EVENT_TRANSFER_COMPLETE:
    {
        PRINTF("TRANSFER COMPLETE\n");
        /* Deactivate SSEL line */
        spi0->Control(ARM_SPI_CONTROL_SS, ARM_SPI_SS_INACTIVE);
    }
    break;

    /* Data lost event */
    case ARM_SPI_EVENT_DATA_LOST:
    {
        PRINTF("MASTER_ARM_SPI_EVENT_DATA_LOST\n");
        /* Abort current transfer */
        spi0->Control(ARM_SPI_ABORT_TRANSFER, 0);
    }
    break;
}
```

Receive:

```c
/* Create an instance of sensor data structure. */
uint8_t sensor_data[12] = {0};
    
spi0->Control(ARM_SPI_CONTROL_SS, ARM_SPI_SS_ACTIVE);
spi0->Receive(sensor_data, 12);

PRINTF("DATA: %d %d %d\n", sensor_data[0], sensor_data[1], sensor_data[2]);
```